# How to get selected option using if condition in play2 Java

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

```
<select class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="name">
    <option>select ..</option>
    <option>MTN</option>
    <option>Tigo</option>
    <option>Airtel</option>
```

if I select one option I do something in my controller

```
Form<Customer> formData = Form.form(Customer.class).bindFromRequest();

<!-- example -->
if (select == tigo){
    Do thing ..
}
```

Comment: i tried but i get un expected tocken in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeded to sent that form data in three different tables according to the selected option

scalla tamplate :

```
   @helper.form(routes.Application.sell_airtime(),'role -> "form") {                                                         <select class="form-control"
                                                        name="user"
                                                        id="user"
                                                        value="user"
                                                        >
                                                            <option value="select">select ..</option>
                                                            <option value="MTN">MTN</option>
                                                            <option value="Tigo">Tigo</option>

                                                        </select>
}
```

* In the controller method :*

```
  Form<Customer_one> formData_one =     Form.form(Customer_one.class).bindFromRequest();
 if (formData_one.get().user.equals("MTN")) {
     Customer_one.save(formData_one.get());
     return ok("Mituyu yagiye kuri MTN successfully");

 }  
elseif {
do s.thing..
}
```